# How to upgrade PostgreSQL to IDENTITY (or alternative)?

Tags: postgresql

NB: Sorry for long post.

I host a [PeerTube](https://github.com/Chocobozzz/PeerTube) instance on OpenBSD 6.7, with PostgreSQL 12.3.

I have troubles regularly with the database, because, I don't know why, the SERIAL thing in Id cause trouble :

```
error[13/07/2020 à 23:01:04] Cannot create video views for video 1004826 in hour 22.
 
{
  "err": {
    "stack": "SequelizeDatabaseError: null value in column \"id\" violates not-null constraint\n    at Query.formatError (/var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v2.3.0-rc.1/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:366:16)\n
...
    "message": "null value in column \"id\" violates not-null constraint",
```

Here, we can see that the thing is supposed to pass a DEFAULT to the Id COLUMN.

```
"sql": "INSERT INTO \"video\" (\"id\",\"uuid\",\"name\",\"category\",\"licence\",\"language\",\"privacy\",\"nsfw\",\"description\",\"support\",\"duration\",\"views\",\"likes\",\"dislikes\",\"remote\",\"url\",\"commentsEnabled\",\"downloadEnabled\",\"waitTranscoding\",\"state\",\"publishedAt\",\"originallyPublishedAt\",\"channelId\",\"createdAt\",\"updatedAt\") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24) RETURNING *;",
```

So after a bit of research, I found about [IDENTITY column](http://dbadailystuff.com/change-serial-to-identity-in-postgresql) and proceed to change a few of them, just to see if it improves the situation.

So I changed the Id column to IDENTITY. But now, I forgot to drop the SEQUENCE (the one that was there in the first place to make things work... ) in the first place. Let's try :

```
peertube_prod2=> DROP SEQUENCE "videoView_id_seq";
ERROR:  cannot drop sequence "videoView_id_seq" because column id of table "videoView" requires it
HINT:  You can drop column id of table "videoView" instead.
```

But I cannot drop the id column. So instead, I copied the id column content in another one. Then dropped the original id column and replaced it with an Identity column (I basically made a swap operation with a temporary column and return to the original name). But I still cannot drop the damn SEQUENCE.

That same operation cannot happen either on some key TABLE (with links to half the rest of the DB).

So actually, the problem has moved. I still cannot update the thing (because the SEQUENCE is still there, even if Id is now an IDENTITY field):

```
warn[02/08/2020 à 11:02:26] Cannot process activity Update.

{
  "err": {
    "stack": "SequelizeDatabaseError: more than one owned sequence found\n    at Query.formatError (/var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v2.3.0/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:366:16)\n
...
    "message": "more than one owned sequence found",
```

Structure of a table after updating to IDENTITY :

```
peertube_prod2=> \d "videoView"
                                    Table "public.videoView"
  Column   |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |             Default
-----------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------
 startDate | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 endDate   | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 views     | integer                  |           | not null |
 videoId   | integer                  |           | not null |
 createdAt | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 col       | integer                  |           |          |
 id        | integer                  |           | not null | generated by default as identity
Indexes:
    "video_view_start_date" btree ("startDate")
    "video_view_video_id" btree ("videoId")
Foreign-key constraints:
    "videoView_videoId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("videoId") REFERENCES video(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

structure of a table from the start :

```
peertube_prod2=> \d "videoComment"
                                            Table "public.videoComment"
       Column       |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                  Default
--------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------
 id                 | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('"videoComment_id_seq"'::regclass)
 url                | character varying(2000)  |           | not null |
 text               | text                     |           | not null |
 originCommentId    | integer                  |           |          |
 inReplyToCommentId | integer                  |           |          |
 videoId            | integer                  |           | not null |
 accountId          | integer                  |           |          |
 createdAt          | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 updatedAt          | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 deletedAt          | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
Indexes:
    "videoComment_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "video_comment_url" UNIQUE, btree (url)
    "video_comment_account_id" btree ("accountId")
    "video_comment_created_at" btree ("createdAt" DESC)
    "video_comment_video_id" btree ("videoId")
    "video_comment_video_id_origin_comment_id" btree ("videoId", "originCommentId")
Foreign-key constraints:
    "videoComment_accountId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("accountId") REFERENCES account(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    "videoComment_inReplyToCommentId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("inReplyToCommentId") REFERENCES "videoComment"(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    "videoComment_originCommentId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("originCommentId") REFERENCES "videoComment"(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    "videoComment_videoId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("videoId") REFERENCES video(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
Referenced by:
    TABLE ""userNotification"" CONSTRAINT "userNotification_commentId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("commentId") REFERENCES "videoComment"(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE ""videoComment"" CONSTRAINT "videoComment_inReplyToCommentId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("inReplyToCommentId") REFERENCES "videoComment"(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE ""videoComment"" CONSTRAINT "videoComment_originCommentId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("originCommentId") REFERENCES "videoComment"(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

I though I could build again an empty database with IDENTITY columns everywhere and then import the data from the current database. Can one do that ?

Or can I upgrade the current database directly ?

Or ... what did I missed ?

Comment: I don't think that changing a sequence-defaulted column to an identity column would even solve your actual problem, which seems to be that the sequelize orm is passing a `null` value for that column instead of omitting it or passing `default`.

Comment: What you missed is 1) @Bergi answer that the issue is passing ```NULL``` to a  ```NOT NULL``` column. 2) That ```IDENTITY``` is backed by a  ```SEQUENCE``` so you have not gotten away from sequences.  To unravel this we will need to see the table schema.

Comment: I added a few things to provide more info after your comments.

To @Bergi :
the app pass `DEFAULT` to the Id COLUMN.

I provided the structure of one table. Or so I think. Do you need more ? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks. Is that what the table schema looked after you changed it to an identity column or before?

Comment: This table is what it looks like now after Id changed to IDENTITY.

I still have several tables with Id as SERIAL if you wish to see.

Comment: I added another table just like it was from the start.

I cannot figure out what is wrong, and yet, somehow, the DEFAULT seems to be sometime not from the SEQUENCE.

Comment: This question is confusing, because it's about inserting into "video" that doesn't work due to the default clause on `id` being wrong, but then you focus on other tables without even looking at the default clause of `video.id`, although these other tables don't seem to have the same problem.

Comment: Actually I had to give up and install again the whole thing...